# Как дать название таблице ManyToMany Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Есть reference entity к самому себе, получается таблица user_user, как переименовать данную таблицу не изменяя связь?

Answer (score 0):

В аннотациях вы можете указывать называние таблиц связи. 
Можете посмотреть внимательнее тут https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_jointable